# Need help for a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have following sample string

`test1/test2/test3:test4/test5/test6IAmInterestedIn:test7/test8`

I am only interested in **test6IAmInterestedIn** which is after fourth slash and can consist of 3 characters, multiple letters and end with 3 digits i.e. `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`.

What I want to add to the above regular expression, that I always pick up the string after the fourth slash which matches `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}`. How can i do so ?

Comment: there are no three digits in that string.

Comment: `^(?:[^/]*/){4}(\w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uS8wY2/1)

```
(?:[^\/]*\/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3})
```

where

- `(?:[^\/]*\/){4}` matches 4 blocks that contain forward slash
- `([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3})` captures your desired pattern