# Regex isn't extracting specific part rather whole string upto the group

Tags: java, regex

This is the follow up to the question that i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528262/need-help-for-a-regular-expression/33528492#33528492)

The given regex is perfect i.e., `(?:[^\/]*\/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3})`. However, when i do it in java, The java matches the string upto the matching group rather just giving me that string.

```
String defaultRegex = "(?:[^\\/]*\\/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3})";
String stringToMatch = "unknown/relevant/nonrelevant:2.2.2/random/ABC123:random/morerandom";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(defaultRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher (stringToMatch);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The above thing is printing `unknown/relevant/nonrelevant:2.2.2/random/ABC123` when I want regex just to give me `ABC123`

Comment: Since you want the group 1: `m.group(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`matcher.group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) as well as `matcher.group(0)` always return the whole matched string.

To get the first capturing group, use [`matcher.group(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29),

The second capturing group goes with `matcher.group(2)`, and so on.