# Regex matching exact # of slashes

Tags: java, regex

Follow up with the [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528262/need-help-for-a-regular-expression/33528492#33528492), This regex isn't working if i put following string.

`test1/test2/test3:test4/test5/test/1234/abc1232323:test7/test8`. It result in abc1232323, however, I Want it to tell me that it didn't find the matching string after 4 "/" (since 1234 doesn't fit the criteria)

I want the regex to mach ABC123 patern (exact lenght) after exact 4 slashes. I will apreciate @ergonaut help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *NOT* find a match in `test1/test2/test3:test4/test5/test/1234/abc1232323:test7/test8` because you need to match 3 digits that are not followed by a digit, use

```
^(?:[^/]*/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}\d{3})(?!\d)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG6jU5/1)

In Java:

```
String reg = "^(?:[^/]*/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}\\d{3})(?!\\d)";
```

The `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails a match if the 3 digits (`\d{3}`) are followed by another digit. **If you do not need that restriction, remove this lookahead**. You can easily see the effect in the online regex demo.

Comment: What about matching only after if there are 4 slashes in the string

Comment: Could you explain a little? You can set a lookahead to check for 4 slashes. What is the expected output for `test1/test2/test3:test4/test5/test/1234/abc1232323:test7/test8`? Perhaps, I was right when I posted my comment and you need an anchor at the start: `"^(?:[^/]*/){4}([A-Za-z]{3}\\d{3})(?!\\d)"`

Comment: `test1/test2/test3:test4/test5/test/1234/abc1232323:test7/test8` should return in "didn't find matching" string. Since the string which appears after 4 slashes doesn't satisfy the criteria of `([A-Za-z]{3}\\d{3})(?!\\d)` ... its `1234` which is all digits